# How to display data from an API based on filter?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Please Help,
This is the API - https://api.covid19api.com/summary

I want to display "TotalConfirmed" (from API) for the selected country from the drop-down list.
Below is my code, the problem in my code is that when I select any country from the drop-down list it displays TotalConfirmed data of Afghanistan ([0] index 0 ), for all the countries.

(coding in React JS)
Live code Link : https://codesandbox.io/s/brave-mayer-fh14v?file=/src/App.js

App.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import TestPicker from "./components/newAPI/TestPicker";
import { fetchData } from "./components/newAPI";

class App extends Component {
  state = {
    data: {},
    country: "",
  };

  handleCountryChange = async (country) => {
    const data = await fetchData(country);
    this.setState({ data: data, country: country });
    console.log(country);
    console.log("data", data);
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <TestPicker handleCountryChange={this.handleCountryChange} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

`
index.js

```
//method for fetchingData
export const fetchData = async (country) => {
   
    if (country) {
            try {
            const { data: { Countries: [{ TotalConfirmed }] } } = await 
            axios.get('https://api.covid19api.com/summary')
            return { TotalConfirmed }
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error)
        }
    }

}

//method for fetchingCountries for drop down list
export const fetchCountries = async () => {
    try {
        const { data: { Countries } } = await axios.get(`${url}`);
        return Countries.map((country) => country.Country);
    }
    catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
}

`.
```

TestPicker.js

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { NativeSelect, FormControl } from '@material-ui/core'
import { fetchCountries } from "./index.js"

const TestPicker = ({handleCountryChange}) => {
const [fetchedCountries, setFetchedCountries] = useState([])
    useEffect(() => {
        const fetchAPI = async () => {
            setFetchedCountries(await fetchCountries());

        }
        fetchAPI();

    }, []);

    return (
        <div className="col-md-9 ms-sm-auto col-lg-10 px-md-4">
            <FormControl>
                <NativeSelect defaultValue="" onChange = {(e)=> 
                     handleCountryChange(e.target.value)}>
                    <option value="global">Global</option>
                    {fetchedCountries.map((country,i) => 
        <option key={i} value={country}>{country}</option>)}
                </NativeSelect>
            </FormControl>
        </div>

    )
}

export default TestPicker
```

Comment: can you provide a live code sample ?  it may easy for debug

Comment: Maybe you can apply javascript filter on the data.

Comment: @Nekromenzer, can you please mention which tool can be used to share React Js live code.

Comment: @aish usually I'm using code sandbox

Comment: Thank You @Nekromenzer, here is the live code link https://codesandbox.io/s/brave-mayer-fh14v?file=/src/App.js - Need solution to console.log "TotalConfirmed" data of the selected country

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//method for fetchingData
export const fetchData = async (country) => {

if (country) {
 try {
    const { data: { Countries: [{ TotalConfirmed }] } } = await 
        axios.get('https://api.covid19api.com/summary')
        return { TotalConfirmed }
        } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
       }
    }
 }
```

I replaced the above code with

```
export async function fetchData(Country) {
  const { data } = await axios.get(`${url}`);
  if (Country === "Global") {
   return console.log(data.Global.TotalConfirmed);
  }
  return data?.Countries?.filter(function (item) {
  return item.Country === Country;
  }).map(function ({ TotalConfirmed }) {
    return TotalConfirmed;
  });
}
```

and get data by in the index  `data[0]`  see the example hope this work , there may be better solution than this

live example - https://codesandbox.io/s/vigorous-torvalds-jwfp3?file=/src/components/index.js:403-741

Comment: Thank you for your time, but it is still showing the "TotalConfirmed" data of index 0 (that is Afghanistan) for other countries as well. When we select the country, in the console you can see the country name and the data{TotalConfirmed: 154585}, I need to console log "TotalConfirmed" data of that particular selected country instead it showing "TotallConfirmed" data of index 0 for all the country

Comment: @aish i see let me try to  find a solution

Comment: @aish https://codesandbox.io/s/vigorous-torvalds-jwfp3?file=/src/App.js I found it was  an issue with  your fetch function and I rewrite it with a map, then it works fine, Sorry for the late replay was busy with another task, good luck

Comment: Great !, Thank you so.... much.

Answer (score 1):

1-define a state and use `seState` in your onChange or onSubmit. This way whenever the user chooses a country, your state will be updated. you can pass the name of the country to it. like `const [chosenCountry,setChosenCountry]=useSate()`.

2-use `useEffect` hook or the life cycle equivalent for that and pass that state as the second argument. Not setState but the state. ( in your code you have `setFetchedCountries` which is wrong. It should be `fetchedCountries`

3-in the `useEffect hook, use` axios`to fetch the data and set the`fetchedCountries` state.

Comment: Thank you Sobhan for correcting that setFetchedCountries, but I didn't get how to make it happen.

Comment: here is the live code link - https://codesandbox.io/s/brave-mayer-fh14v?file=/src/App.js